# How can I draw iterating ul-li List pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to draw the Html as in the Preview.

To see preview [click here](http://pastehtml.com/view/dd9ttlh4x.html). View [Source](http://pastie.org/8258601) of the page to view the ul -li rendering.
For this I wrote a method shown below

```
private void DrawTree(HtmlGenericControl ParentULTag, int count)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl ChildLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl ChildUl = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            ChildLi.Controls.Add(ChildUl);
            ParentULTag.Controls.Add(ChildLi);
            ChildLi.InnerText = i.ToString();
            DrawTree(ChildUl, i);
        }
    }
```

But it Draw it like this

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I Initiated the method in the pageload as shown

```
HtmlGenericControl Initial = new HtmlGenericControl("ul"); 
DrawTree(Initial,4);
```

Whats the mistake in this code?

Comment: It seems like there should be two loops, no need for recursion.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM then how it would be?

Comment: I don't want a two for loop method. I want to draw it recursively. This is not the real case I need.

Comment: I don't understand, A solution with two loops does exactly what you need; you have only two level of nesting, Check my answer.

Comment: @Ahamed KRAIEM Really I don't want this numbering system. I want to draw a parent- child relationship from database.

Comment: @SubinJacob Then you'd need to accept as input, enough information to build the tree.  You'd need to accept the tree structure in some other form, or a collection of parent/child relationships, or something else from which you can build the tree.  The example that you provided for this question with your numbers is an example that always has *exactly* a depth of 2, never more, because there is no way to communicate how deep it should go based on the input to the function.

Comment: @servy Yes, seems to be. Please ignoRE thee html then. I want the recursive loop to draw the content. As shownn in the code the depth is depended on thethe input. I just want to know why the first loop is only drawn.

Comment: @SubinJacob But that's just it; your example code *doesn't* logically lend itself to a recursive approach.  Why does the first level get expanded but the second level doesn't?  The function call would look the same with your signature.  If you want to build a tree you need to have a tree-based structure as input, not just a single number.  When you get the information needed in the output into the input, then we can talk.  Until then, it's simply not possible.

Comment: @Servy I want it likeike this. Each of the four children have 3 children. Each off those children have 2 children andnd soo on. Thus the recursion ends. Here the input of the function is number of children and the ul tag. ( sorry, typo- onn mobile)

Comment: @SubinJacob But that's not what your "expected output" shows.  It shows it going to a depth of 2 and then magically stopping.  If it were truly recursive it would actually result in infinite recursion, as you aren't "reducing" the problem size at all.  If you input 1 it would have 1 child, and that child should have a child, and the child's child should have a child, and so on forever.  The only reason it doesn't go on forever is because your output isn't recursive, it just magically goes to a depth of exactly 2.

Comment: @servy I hope itt does because, when its 4 it is only upto 3 for next recursion. When 3 its only upto two.

Comment: @SubinJacob That's not what your example shows.  In it the element `1` has one child, not zero.  The element `2` has two children, not one.  The element `3` has three children, not two.  All of those children have zero children, instead of the 0, 1, 2, or 3 that they should have, were this actually recursive.

Comment: That was a bad example, please ignore it.

Comment: @servy if you have parent child table in your db and have to draw a structure using li and ull how will u do?

Comment: @SubinJacob That depends on how your input is structured.  There are many ways to represent a tree structure, and what you happen to have is quite relevant.  I've been asking you to describe how your actual data is structured from the start.  You have yet to provide it.

Comment: @servy A parent and child column. Child can be a parent. Sory, I m on mobile and its difficult to use formating. Anyway thanks for the downvote and close vote.

Comment: @SubinJacob When you provide the information that I asked of you 3 hours ago, and the question again becomes answerable, we can talk further.  Complaining about downvotes/close votes on a question that you refuse to provide the required information for is not going to make the question any more answerable.

Comment: @servy I will update the question tomorrow. I already wrote ann algorithm for this before. But this time I was looking for a better one and ended here like this.

Comment: @Servy the question is updated. please refer this link to see the preview http://pastehtml.com/view/dd9ttlh4x.html

Comment: @servy Now the question is very much clear I think. please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple

```
 private void DrawTree(HtmlGenericControl ParentULTag, int count)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl ChildLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl ChildUl = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            ChildLi.InnerText = i.ToString();
            ChildLi.Controls.Add(ChildUl);
            DrawTree(ChildUl, i);
            ParentULTag.Controls.Add(ChildLi);
        }
    }
```

Please note the position of line `ChildLi.InnerText = i.ToString();`
 **but still don't know why its so**

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    private static HtmlGenericControl GenerateList(int count)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl parent = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl ChildLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            ChildLi.InnerText = i.ToString();
            HtmlGenericControl ChildUl = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            ChildLi.Controls.Add(ChildUl);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                HtmlGenericControl FinalLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                FinalLi.InnerText = j.ToString();
                ChildUl.Controls.Add(FinalLi);
            }
            parent.Controls.Add(ChildLi);
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

Edit:

You should represent your input as a tree structure. Here I used a `Node` object that has an `ID` and `Children` properties:

```
class Node
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Node[] Children { get; set; }
    public Node(int id, Node[] children)
    {
        ID = id;
        Children = children;
    }
    public Node(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Children = new Node[] { };
    }
}

class Program
{

    public static HtmlGenericControl GetList(Node root)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
        GetListImpl(root, ul);
        return ul;
    }

    private static void GetListImpl(Node root, HtmlGenericControl rootElement)
    {
        foreach (var item in root.Children)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            li.InnerText = item.ID.ToString();
            if (item.Children.Length > 0)
                li.Controls.Add(GetList(item));

            rootElement.Controls.Add(li);
        }
    }

    public static string HtmlGenericControlToString(HtmlGenericControl control)
    {
        string contents = null;
        using (System.IO.StringWriter swriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);
            control.RenderControl(writer);
            contents = swriter.ToString();
        }
        return contents;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node root = new Node(0,
            new Node[]{
                new Node(1, new Node[]{
                    new Node(1),
                    new Node(2)
                }),
                 new Node(2, new Node[]{
                    new Node(1),
                    new Node(2, new Node[]{
                        new Node(1)
                    })
                })
            });
        var ul = GetList(root);
        var html = HtmlGenericControlToString(ul);
        Console.WriteLine(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: please see the updated question. Really I wanted a parent - child structure. But I made mistakes in the Example question. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
HtmlGenericControl Initial = new HtmlGenericControl("ul"); 
DrawTree(ref Initial,4);
```

now method

```
private void DrawTree(ref HtmlGenericControl ParentULTag, int count)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl ChildLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlGenericControl ChildUl = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            ChildLi.Controls.Add(ChildUl);
            ParentULTag.Controls.Add(ChildLi);
            ChildLi.InnerText = i.ToString();
            DrawTree(ref ChildUl, i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `HtmlGenericControl` is already a reference type. Then should I ??